# Full screen metro apps on windows 10 are not listed using EnumWindows

Tags: windows, winapi, callback, windows-10, win-universal-app

Full screen metro application windows are not listed when using EnumWindows API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Those windows are listed when in restored or maximized mode, but fails when in full screen mode. Note that all metro applications do not have a full screen mode. The application I tried was the gaming application named 3D Chess Game, and the call back function given in the EnumWindows API was not invoked for the 3D chess Game full screen window, while it was called for all other top level windows on screen.
What could be the reason for this behaviour? Is there an alternative way to enumerate through the full screen metro app windows?

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: edited the question for better clarity.

Comment: Full screen metro apps don't have Win32 windows

Comment: Nice question, and I would also like to know, how to handle this. By the way, I would also like to know, how to hook metro-apps properly, as we could do with global hooks in earlier windows versions. Perhaps the inability to hook metro apps like former ones and this api-omitting are even related. I will wait and check the answers,

Comment: Why do you want to do this? there may be an alternative way to achieve your actual goal

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Full screen metro apps don't have Win32 windows" In what sense? They have their own window handles and you can minimize, restore and activate them using the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `EnumWindows` not enumerate the full screen metro (UWP) apps, but if you know the window title, you can retrive its handle using [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww):

```
var hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Full screen window title");
```

If you don't know the title of the window or you want to enumerate all windows, regardless of their title, you have to call [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128785/12653813).