# Get a list of open application windows in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a C++ program to list all my currently open windows (e.g. browser, file explorer, Discord) and their position/dimensions. So far I have managed to list all windows using `EnumWindows`, but it includes many unnamed windows and things like Program Manager, Settings (which I don't have open) and NVIDIA GeForce Overlay.

How can I filter out windows that are not in the Alt+Tab menu or Taskbar?

My current code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

BOOL IsAltTabWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    HWND hwndWalk = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);
    HWND hwndTry;

    while ((hwndTry = GetLastActivePopup(hwndWalk)) != hwndTry)
    {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwndTry))
            break;
        hwndWalk = hwndTry;
    }

    LONG_PTR extendedStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);

    return (hwndWalk == hwnd) && ((extendedStyle & WS_EX_APPWINDOW) != 0 || (extendedStyle & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) == 0);
}

BOOL CALLBACK WindowCallback(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const DWORD TITLE_SIZE = 1024;
    TCHAR windowTitle[TITLE_SIZE];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, windowTitle, TITLE_SIZE);

    if (IsAltTabWindow(hwnd) && IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        std::cout << "Window (" << IsAltTabWindow(hwnd) << "): " << windowTitle << std::endl;

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    EnumWindows(WindowCallback, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863

Comment: Be aware that some processes (e.g. database servers) might run, consume resources, and not have any open windows. With [Qt](https://qt.io/) you probably could code a graphical application which runs sometimes without showing any window on the screen

Answer (score 2):

Which windows appear on the Taskbar is documented on MSDN:

[The Taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar)

> ...
>
> The Shell places a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates an unowned window—that is, a window that does not have a parent and that has the appropriate extended style bits (see [Managing Taskbar Buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#managing-taskbar-buttons), below). To switch to a window, the user clicks its window button. This functionality has been greatly expanded as of Windows 7. For more information, see [Taskbar Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions).
>
> ...
>
> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.
>
> The Shell will remove a window's button from the taskbar only if the window's style supports visible taskbar buttons. If you want to dynamically change a window's style to one that does not support visible taskbar buttons, you must hide the window first (by calling `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE`), change the window style, and then show the window.
>
> ...

Which windows appear in the <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd> window is discussed on
Raymond Chen's blog:

[Which windows appear in the Alt+Tab list?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863)

> ...
>
> Note: The details of this algorithm are an implementation detail. It can change at any time, so don’t rely on it. In fact, it already changed with Flip and Flip3D; I’m just talking about the Classic Alt+Tab window here.
>
> For each visible window, walk up its owner chain until you find the root owner. Then walk back down the visible last active popup chain until you find a visible window. If you’re back to where you’re started, then put the window in the Alt+Tab list. In pseudo-code:
>
> ```
> BOOL IsAltTabWindow(HWND hwnd)
> {
>  // Start at the root owner
>  HWND hwndWalk = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);
>  // See if we are the last active visible popup
>  HWND hwndTry;
>  while ((hwndTry = GetLastActivePopup(hwndWalk)) != hwndTry) {
>   if (IsWindowVisible(hwndTry)) break;
>   hwndWalk = hwndTry;
>  }
>  return hwndWalk == hwnd;
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> At least that’s the simple rule if you’re not playing crazy window style games. The `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` and `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended styles were created so people can play games and put their window in the Alt+Tab list or take it out even if the simple rule would normally have decided otherwise. ...
>
> ...
>
> A window with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style is treated as if it weren’t visible, even if it is. A window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style is treated as if it has no owner, even if it does.
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After adding the ancestor walking from the MSDN article and checking for `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` and `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` in the extended styles, I still have two 'Settings' windows and a 'Windows Input Experience' window (+ a few others) get listed while not having settings open. Is there something else I can do to fix this?

Comment: @SirGolem please update your question to show the latest code you are having trouble with.

Comment: I've updated the question to my latest code.

Answer (score 0):

The [ScreenCaptureforHWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/a59e7586c0bd1a967e1e25f6ca0363e20151afe5/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/ScreenCaptureforHWND/Win32WindowEnumeration.h#L45) sample shows a workable function. But as @Sthealt01 said in his question, [Show a list of all "Alt+Tab windows" (even full screen UWP windows) and retrieve the handle of the one picked by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069771/show-a-list-of-all-alttab-windows-even-full-screen-uwp-windows-and-retrieve),

> neither EnumWindows nor EnumChildWindows retrieve the handles of the
> root owners of full screen UWP windows. However EnumChildWindows retrieves their child windows, and each UWP window has a child window whose class name is ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow (and other child windows).

He had improved the function in his answer of himself question.

the ScreenCaptureforHWND code:

```
bool IsAltTabWindow(Window const& window)
{
    HWND hwnd = window.Hwnd();
    HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();

    auto title = window.Title();
    auto className = window.ClassName();

    if (hwnd == shellWindow)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (title.length() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOT) != hwnd)
    {
        return false;
    }

    LONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    if (!((style & WS_DISABLED) != WS_DISABLED))
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD cloaked = FALSE;
    HRESULT hrTemp = DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_CLOAKED, &cloaked, sizeof(cloaked));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrTemp) &&
        cloaked == DWM_CLOAKED_SHELL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```