How to get a list of all running GUI apps means processes that have a window attached? using python
I have searched extensively for a solution and discovered the psutil library. While I've managed to retrieve all running processes using psutil, I'm struggling to segregate them into GUI applications and background processes, similar to how Windows Task Manager does.
def is_gui_process(process):
    # check if the process have a window attached.

processes = psutil.process_iter()

def segregate_processes(processes):
    """Segregate processes into GUI apps and background processes."""
    gui_processes = []
    background_processes = []
    for process in processes:
        if is_gui_process(process):
            gui_processes.append(process)
        else:
            background_processes.append(process)
    return gui_processes, background_processes

I want the result segregated in Gui Apps and Background processes.Windows Task manager segregating the processes
Thank you in advance!

Please edit your post to include the current version of your code. What is currently shown is not valid python code and is therefore not reproducible

yeah, it's not a valid python code, i just put it as an example for the code i want. I am not able to find the code to achieve my goal.

How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process? In short: The information is useless. It's an arbitrary grouping that serves no practical purpose.

There is nothing specific to a process that tells you whether it is a GUI or not. You could use the Python win32 package to enumerate all Windows and then match the process ids, but I am not sure even that would give you a definitive list. Maybe you need to rethink exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

@IInspectable yeah no problem with arbitrary grouping. if it possible to achieve the same thing using python, the solution will be appreciated.

@OldBoy I want to check remotely whether the user is doing some task in his system or not (task means if he is opened filmora, ms excel or any type of windows application), if it is possible using win32 package which you have suggested, can you please give some snippets or sample of the code.

Scrap psutil then, and enumerate top-level windows instead (EnumWindows()). Once you have a window handle you can get the owning process and thread id (GetWindowThreadProcessId()). Open the process, make sure to check creation time and find the executable used to start the process. All of that is rather intricate.

The only way you could do this remotely is by having some application running in the user's system which you could poll via TCP/IP or similar. And why would anyone allow you to get that sort of access in the first place?

Does the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069771/show-a-list-of-all-alttab-windows-even-full-screen-uwp-windows-and-retrieve work for you?

Thankyou @IInspectable, I am able to achieve my goal with your solution. I am using "pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(window)" and "win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)" , it solved my problem.
